# While loop taking so much time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

In my stored procedure, I have 2 while loops and I need to avoid those loops and use cursor or recursive cte

```
create procedure Parent_Child_UserDetails_Schedule  
as  
begin  
    Set nocount on  

    create table #temptab(id int, userid int, parentid int)   

    select userid, 1 as valid 
    into #users 
    from userdetails 
    where isactive = 1  

    truncate table Parent_Child_UserDetails  

    while(select count(*) from #users where valid = 1) > 0  
    begin  
        declare @userid  int  

        select top 1 @userid = userid 
        from #users 
        where valid = 1   

        truncate table #temptab  

        insert into #temptab(id, userid, parentid)  
        values(1, @userid, @userid)  

        declare @id int            
        set @id = 1

        while((select count(*) from userdetails
               where parentid in (select userid from #temptab where id=@id ) and isactive = 1) > 0)            
        begin            
            insert into #temptab (id, userid, parentid) 
                select @id + 1, userid, @userid  
                from userdetails 
                where parentid in (select userid from #temptab where id = @id) 
                  and isactive = 1

            set @id= @id + 1
         end   

         insert into Parent_Child_UserDetails(Parentid, Userid)
             select parentid, userid 
             from #temptab   

         update #users 
         set valid = 0 
         where userid = @userid  
    end  

    drop table #temptab  
    drop table #users  

    Set nocount off  
end
```

Please help me .....

Comment: Post your table structure, existing data example and desired output/how you want the tables to look at the end of the process. Picking apart that code and writing something set based that does the same thing is a big ask when we can't see the data it works on or what it should produce, other than by picking through the code

Comment: Don't use loops in SQL. Use a set based approach instead. To help us help you, please note that sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: @ZoharPeled sample data even iam not having  the table is having millions of data iam not understanding what they are doing please try to understand

Comment: if you can, try and think of how to make the inner loop into a set based operation.  A cursor may not be much faster.

Comment: It would help to answer the question if you could provide just a few records of the sample data and the desired results. This way, we could check our code before posting an answer.

Comment: Using a Cursor or rCTE are probably not going to make things any/much better here. A `WHILE` is simply a different way of writing a cursor, where as an rCTE can be a form of RBAR as well. (Some like `WITH C AS (SELECT 0 AS I UNION ALL SELECT I + 1 FROM C WHERE I +1 < 50) SELECT I FROM C;` is actually an RBAR process, for example). The fact that you are using a hierarchy means that an rCTE is likely to be RBAR as well; but without knowing the data, expected results, etc, that's a guess.

Comment: Seems like the `Parent_Child_UserDetails` should hold all the `parentId` and `userId` from `userdetails` where both of them are marked as active. Is that correct?

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes

Answer (score 1):

Following our conversation in the comments, what you need is to insert to the `Parent_Child_UserDetails` table all the parent ids and user ids where both are active, 
you can replace that [RBAR](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/) nightmare of a code with a single `insert....select` statement, like this:

```
insert into Parent_Child_UserDetails(Parentid, Userid)
select parentid, userid 
from userdetails as t0
where isactive = 1
and exists
(
    select 1
    from userdetails as t1
    where t1.isavtice = 1
    and t1.userId = t0.ParentId
)
```